# How to change the "fullpath" property of References in VBA (Tools -> Refences)?

Tags: excel, vba, reference, updates

I'm sure that there are different ways to phrase this question, but that is the end result that I want to achieve.

So, I have a setup where code is written in C# and added as functions to Excel. It relies on having a specific .tlb file in the Tools->References that can be found in the VBA window.

While I was testing this, the .tlb file (and the rest of them) was on my local drive, but now that the project is working, I need to transfer it to a network drive. The problem is that I can't find any way to change the actual file (or filepath) that is being referenced - it's always looking at my local path.

I've tried a few things:

Followed the steps listed here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/308340/how-to-check-and-remove-incorrect-project-references-in-the-visual-bas

Tried several VBA codes using the `.References.Remove` expression. This does not actually remove the reference from the list, it only unticks it.

I've tried to remove the file from my local drive (causing an Excel error that a reference has been moved, deleted or renamed - good) and then add a reference from the new location that I want. This resulted in one of two things:

1) If I try to add it manually - nothing happens, the existing reference remains unticked and nothing new is added (that I know of).

2) If I try to do it via `.References.AddFromFile "filepath"` expression it ticks the reference, if it was unticked (this does **not** make the external formulas work), or an error that a reference with such a name already exists, if it was ticked.

Comment: Wild guess: have you tried looking into registries and removing the reference that way. You can then re add it with the network location.. maybe.. just guessing, haven't actually looked into it myself

Comment: @Zac I was thinking that that may solve it, but I don't know where these are stored in the registry. Do you have any insight with that or should I ask ol' Google?

Comment: :) Google is where i would have started.. unfortunately it's not something i can do at work (although might do over the weekend). I have done something similar for a different application and it did work for me. Just have to identify where in registry these are.. easier said then done

Comment: [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com/) has a utility to set and remove references. Maybe it can help.

Answer (score 0):

Recompile on the network drive with the following silly way.

Open the VBA editor
Go into each module
Insert a line (doesn't matter what you write)
Press ENTER
Remove the line that you've inserted
When finished, in the menu click Debug \ Compile

Source: by Andreas Killer
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/ms-excel-error-cannot-run-the-macro-the-macros-may/3f3106b2-ae60-4d21-ac94-67e54e605922